# Вернуть нужную ошибку во время валидации данных

Tags: c++, архитектура

```
class DataChecker{
    public:
        int check(data){
            return checkData(data);
        }
    private:
        int checkData(data){
            int res = 0;
            res = checkDataForFulFillment(data);
            if(res){return res;}
            res = validateData(data);
            if(res){return res;}
            res = checkDataForSize(data);
            if(res){return res;}

        }
        checkDataForFulFillment(data){
            if(bad){
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        validateData(data){
            if(bad1){
                return 2;
            }
            if(bad2){
                return 3;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        checkDataForSize(data){
            if(bad){
                return 4;
            }
            return 0;
        }
};
```

Пусть имеем датаЧекер, который должен проверять данные и выплюнуть ошибку наверх в случае чего. Меня смущает метод `checkData`, который после каждой проверки должен проверить результат и выплюнуть самую актуальную ошибку. Кажется, тут было бы верно полиморфизмом каждую проверку затащить и хранить внутри каждой сущности результат, а потом первый найденный результат отдать наверх. Так и в цикле можно будет вызывать все проверки, а не руками, и как - будто лучше архитектурно. Что-то вот затрудняюсь в приянтии решения. Помогите разобраться

PS: код примерный, в жизни checkDataForFulFillment, validateData и все подобные это отдельные классы и проверяют они на какие-то особые свойства из предметной области. Все return возвращают enum. Ну и реализация методов не лежит в объяявлении класса :D

Comment: Есть такая рекомандация - предпочитать композицию наследованию. Если все проверки однородны, то это должен быть один класс с нужными методами. Если проверки касаются разных вещей (например, проверить дату, потом проверить роль юзера, итд), то я бы сделал отдельные не связанные друг с другом валидаторы для проверки и вызывал бы их из какого то мега-валидатора (см паттерны композит, стратегия)

Comment: Массив указателей на методы валидации не подходит? Итерируйся по ним. Вообще пофиг, если у тебя там не космический корабль, то не думаю, что это важно. Почему бы просто не кидать ошибку через `throw`? И нужна ли валидация при вызове? Может её проще и правильнее как `RAII` сделать?

Comment: Правильные решения приходят в конкретной ситуации. *Не плоди сущности без необходимости.*

Comment: Для того и придуманы исключения...

Answer (score 0):

По сути ты прав. Обычно делают интерфейс а-ля IValidator, который условно имеет метод validate. В самом классе DataChecker у тебя просто массив валидаторов, причем ты можешь даже где-нибудь в конфиге по умному настраивать порядок валидации, например, у тебя данные должны быть подписаны, если они не подписаны нет смысла их дальше проверять.
Крч добавляешь интерфейс IValidator, у него метод validate, а какие-то хитрые параметры передаешь через конструктор.